# An example on how to convert this data format to JSON?

Tags: json

Can someone provide me an example on how to convert this data format to JSON?

```
@Scsi_test
(iotest)
scsi
dkdkdkdkdkdkddk
dkdkdkdkdkkdkdk
dkdkdkdkkdkdkdk
```

Comment: There's no obvious formatting to the data you've provided, so you'll need to tell us what you're trying to achieve here. (Additionally, what language are you using?)

Comment: Once converted to JSON data format. I would like to read it using jquery json

Comment: @BWR Do you mean it's just a semirandom chunk of text?  No fields no nothing?

Comment: each data format starts with the @ symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you haven't given us any clues at all what the data format is.
So based on what I see in your question, just 6 rows of data, I would suggest:

```
{rows:{row1:'@Scsi_test',row2:'(iotest)',row3:'scsi',row4:'dkdkdkdkdkdkddk',row5:'dkdkdkdkdkdkddk',row6:'dkdkdkdkdkdkddk'}}
```

Comment: Thanks Magnus, you given me a better ideal how to build on this json knowledge